# Google Chrome extension JS doesn't function as expected

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to change the default behavior of the hyperlink on Google Sheets. It's currently opening hyperlinks in a new tab in a new tab. What I want to do is, to open them on a popup window.

[image]

As there's no `target` option for the default `HYPERLINK()` function of sheets,  I decided to go with a Chrome Extension. Here's how it looks like:

```
Manifest.json

{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Google Sheets Clicker",
  "version": "0.1",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": [
      "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets*"
    ],
    "js": ["jq.js", "content.js"]
  }

]
}
```

And the `content.js` (for testing purposes, I'm just alerting the url)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('body').on('click', 'a', function(){
     var url = $(this).attr('href');
     alert(url);
     return false;
   });
});
```

But it's not triggering the function when the hyperlink get's clicked on the sheets window.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Instead try to just jquery the href html tag
$("a").on("click",....)